# How to test the bad cases?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, automated-tests

Given that there are plenty of libraries for generating mock/fake data starting from a JSON schema or a Mongoose model and so on, how to test the behavior of a sw (let's say a web api) for the wrong data cases.
For example let's say I have a user service with name, email, phone, etc and a deep description of its fields data content. Let's say I have also different error codes that should be thrown for each possible error. I can't understand how to programmatically produce bad mock data (wrong email, bad formed name, etc) to put inside a test.
Moreover are there some test-process specs for these cases?
Thanks!

---- Integration for to answer to TGW: I'm doing standard tests, something like:

```
const app = require(-myapp-); //express or whatever app
const userModel = require('-myModelDefinition-); //e.g. json schema
const mockingLibrary = require(-mockingLibrary-); //Sinon or any other 


//I'll test that the user->create method works properly on good input
const fakeUser = mockingLibrary.mock(userModel); 
describe('\'users\' service', () => {
  it('create method - good case',()=>{
    return app.service('users')
              .create(fakeUser)
              .should.eventually
              .have.property('_id'); //or any other test
   });
});
//What if I want to test on bad input?
const fakeUserWithErrorOnEmail = mockingLibrary.mock(userModel,{errorOn:'email'}); 
describe('\'users\' service', () => {
  it('create method - bad email case',done=>{
    return app.service('users')
              .create(fakeUserWithErrorOnEmail)
              should.be.rejectedWith(Error, "email-error-message");
   });
});
```

So what I'm looking for, maybe, is a mocking library able to produce both good and bad mock data given the description/schema of good ones.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v2.1.0/mocks/) could help you sinon js mocks allow you to mock API reponses.

Comment: Thanks TGW. I know Sinon and it is just part of the answer. Sinon and other such libraries produce mock data after you define how should data look like. I would like to have a Sinon-like library that produce also some bad data to test what happens when the consumer of my API provides invalid/bad input. E.g. in the users service I would like to have also some mock users with a bad email, and some mock users with invalid name given I described how should a well formed user look like.

Comment: sorry for trouble but can you show me some sample of how you are working with positive data(gooddata) currently, a code sample or something?